How to resize on asset level with data format png using Flutter?
I am making an App using Flutter, but the asset image does not fit well into the FrontEnd, was wondering how to resize it on asset level, maybe using ClipRect
code:
Image.asset("assets/stars_icon.png", width: 50, height: 50,),
I tried using width, and height property of the asset but it scales the asset instead resizing it

The best solution i have found that works for me is :
Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/images/other/logo.png',
                  )
              )
            ),
          ),

Other alternatives you can use are : CircleAvatar, ClipRRect.

Ah I forgot to wrap it using Container lol

You made me laugh, @shotmeinthehead, don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful.

Alrighty done it, thanks for the reminder
